# Firestore relationship

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone explain how to organize the relationship between objects using Spring Boot and Firestore?

I am using spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-firestore and I have two objects that must be located in different collections:

```
@Document(collectionName = "action_task")
public class ActionTask {

    @DocumentId
    private String id;
    ...........................
    
    private EventRule eventRule;
}

@Document(collectionName = "event_rule")
public class EventRulePair {

    @DocumentId
    private String id;

    ...................

    private String code;

    private String eventType;

    private Instant createdAt;
}
```

How organize relationships in the code and haw store in DB?

Comment: You're referring to how to save them in the database?

Comment: How organize relationships in the code and haw store in DB?

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: Data modeling is (as Alex commented) highly specific on the use-cases you want to implement. Unless you have a specific use-case in mind, I recommend watching the excellent video series: [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video)